# Puppet how to tell if a variable is set

Tags: puppet

In a puppet class how should I test if a variable has been set or not?  Right now I am just checking if a variable is undefined:

```
if $http_port != undef {
  $run_command = "$run_command --http-port $http_port"
}
```

Is there a better way to check if a variable has been declared or not?

Comment: You could just set a default value in your class parameters. That would be cleaner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are testing if an variable is undef, your way is correct. Writing

```
if $http_port {
  $run_command = "$run_command --http-port $http_port"
}
```

would accomplish almost the same. If $http_port is undef or false, it will not run the command.

If you want to test if the var has been defined you should do:

```
if defined('$http_port') {
  $run_command = "$run_command --http-port $http_port"
}
```

See https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/function.html#defined.

If the var is a class variable you could do something like:

```
class your_class (
Optional[Integer[0, 65535]] $http_port = undef,
) {
    if $http_port {
      notify { "got here with http_port=${http_port}": }
    }
}
```

It will then only run the notify if the class is declared with http_port set as an integer between 0 and 65535.

Comment: In the above examples, it's not clear to me how `if $http_port {` and `if defined('$http_port') {` differ in terms of what they consider to be true/false. Can someone explain, please?

Comment: @Jimadine `if $http_port` is considered `true` only when `$http_port` is `defined` and is set to `true`. In all other cases this condition is not satisfied (is false).
On the other hand `if defined('$http_port')` validates only whether variable `$http_port` is set to any value (is defined by value). In all other cases this condition will fail.

Comment: @DanielHajduk Thank you for the explanation! Makes sense now.

Comment: Per this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74111016/puppet-manifest-check-if-variable-is-not-empty  , this similar did not work, possibly not compatible with all version of puppet.